# Printing an array of characters

Tags: c, c-strings

I have an array of characters declared as:

```
char *array[size];
```

When I perform a

```
printf("%s", array);
```

it gives me some garbage characters, why it is so?

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/printf/

This url indicates printf takes in the format of: `int printf ( const char * format, ... );

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define size 20
#define buff 100
char line[buff];

int main ()
{
    char *array[100];
    char *sep = " \t\n";

    fgets(line, buff, stdin);

    int i;

    array[0] = strtok(line, sep);

    for (i = 1; i < size; i++) {
        array[i] = strtok(NULL, sep);

        if (array[i] == NULL)
            break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That is an array of pointers, not characters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your array is not initialized, and also you have an array of pointers, instead of an array of char's.  It should be `char* array = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*size);`, if you want an array of char's.  Now you have a pointer to the first element of the array.

Comment: `new` is not an operator in `C`

Answer (score 7):

You declare an array of characters like so:

```
char foo[size];
```

You seem to have it mixed up with `char *`, which is a pointer to a character. You could say

```
char *bar = foo;
```

which would make `bar` point to the contents of `foo`. (Or, actually, to the first character of `foo`.)

To then print the contents of the array, you can do one of the following:

```
// either print directly from foo:
printf("%s", foo);
// or print through bar:
printf("%s", bar);
```

Note, however, that C performs no initialization of the contents of variables, so unless you specifically set the contents to something, you'll get garbage. In addition, if that garbage doesn't happen to contain a `\0`; that is, a char with value 0, it will keep on outputting past the end of the array.

Comment: `&foo` is of type `char(*)[size]`: it isn't really compatible with `char*`, the type of `bar`. You *could say*: `char *bar = foo;`

Comment: @pmg: That'll teach me not to write C code without testing it. Fixed, thanks. :)

Answer (score 4):

Why are we making such a simple thing sound so difficult?

```
char array[SIZE];
... /* initialize array */
puts(array);   /* prints the string/char array and a new line */
/* OR */
printf("%s", array); /* prints the string as is, without a new line */
```

The *char* in *array* after the end of what you want to be your string (ie. if you want your string to read "Hello" that would be the next char after the 'o') must be the terminating NUL character '\0'. If you use a C function to read input that would automatically be appended to the end of your buffer. You would only need to worry about doing it manually if you were individually writing characters to your buffer or something for some reason.

EDIT: As with pmg's comment, the '\0' goes wherever you want the *string* to end, so if you wanted to shorten your string you could just move it up closer to the front, or to have an *empty string* you just have `array[0] = '\0';`. Doing so can also be used to tokenise smaller strings inside a single buffer, just as *strtok* does. ie. "Part1\0Part2\0Part3\0". But I think this is getting away from the scope of the question.

ie. you wanted to store the first 3 chars of the alphabet as a string (don't know why anyone would do it this way but it's just an example):

```
char array[4];
array[0] = 'a';
array[1] = 'b';
array[2] = 'c';
array[3] = '\0';
printf("%s\n", array);
```

If you have something like `char array[] = "Hello";` the '\0' is automatically added for you.

Comment: -1: `printf(array)` does not "print the string as is". It **interprets** the string causing Undefined Behaviour it it contains any conversion specification. Use `printf("%s", array)` instead.

Comment: woops my bad, c+p the puts(array) and changed it to printf. That was a pretty bad fail, prone to format string exploits too.

Comment: Just revoked the -1. Now there's just a minor point in your answer: the zero terminator does not need to be the last char in the array. This is perfectly valid (though useless): `char foo[7] = "foo\0bar";` --- `foo[6]` is `'r'`; `puts(foo);` outputs `"foo\n"`

Comment: Yeah I guess I didn't structure what I was saying very well, let me fix that. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

```
char *array[size];
```

`array` is not a `char *` with that, it's more like a `char **` (pointer to an array of chars, with is similar to pointer to pointer to char).

If all you need is a C string, either:

```
char array[size];
```

and make sure you 0-terminate it properly, or

```
char *array;
```

and make sure you properly allocate and free storage for it (and 0-terminate it too).

Comment: what do you mean by zero terminate the pointer to array of chars

Comment: Strings in C are just an array of char values. The end of the string is signified by a char with the value 0.

Comment: @liangteh In C all the string must be null terminated, so the last character must be a '\0' (a char of value 0)

Comment: there is no way I can use printf to print the array except for looping the array and check for NULL ?

Comment: That's not it at all. `printf` will do that if you pass it a `char*` and use the `%s` format specifier. BUT if your string doesn't end with a `0` (this is not a pointer, it is a char), it will go on and print whatever is stored in memory after your string, causing undefined behavior.

Comment: I printed the char *array[size] by puts(*array) it only print 1 word... can you explain how does the printing works?

Comment: Not without seeing your code. I can't guess what array is initialized to, and string handling is covered in hundreds of books and tutorials that are easy to find.

Comment: @Mat I dont understand the examples given online. It has very simple array accessing examples.

Comment: Then pick up a C book, or look for other examples online. This is basic C.